# Is this Codeigniter 3.0 compatible?

Tags: codeigniter

Can someone tell me if this code is codeigniter 3.0 compatible ?
If not, how should it be formatted?

```
if ( ! function_exists('get_site_url'))
{
    function get_site_url($data){
        $CI =& get_instance();
        //$data = '';
        //echo base_url(); exit;
        $data =str_replace('{SITE_URL}',base_url(),$data);
        return $data;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`SITE_URL` is constant that you define using `define('SITE_URL','value')`.So no need quotes `''`.Try like this..

```
if ( ! function_exists('get_site_url'))
 {
function get_site_url($data){
    $CI =& get_instance();
    //$data = '';
    //echo base_url(); exit;
    $data =str_replace(SITE_URL,base_url(),$data);
    return $data;
}
}
```

> In order to use `base_url()` don't forget to load `url` helper in
>   `application/config/autoload.php`

Comment: Did you try `<?php echo get_site_url($common_row['services']);?>` in view?

Comment: Hi, I tried that, this time the error is not poping up BUT there's no content appearing ...
print_r($common_row); die(); echoes the digit 0 ( zero ).
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

As you pass the `$data['common_row'`] into the view section
`$this->load->view('home_view',$data)` the data has been converted into a array is not object so when you are trying to get the data in the view you can try something like this `<?php echo get_site_url($common_row['services']);?>` or `<?php echo get_site_url($common_row[0]['services']);?>` depending upon the result.

You can debug the code and see the actual value by

`print_r($common_row); die();` on the view page.